# Want to wordpress theme reorgnise

Tags: wordpress, themes

Hi all I need help and have no idea of how to re-organise this theme by recoding

http://c11.cc5.myftpupload.com/

basically I want all jobs posted right at the top is there a quick and easy way to do so?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO, here we prefer to see the relevant code directly in the question rather than external links

Answer (score 0):

but its a theme, I wanted to see if someone has a clue where the problem lies and then I'd  paste the relevant code